# How to mapping a file by matching data using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have some folder. Inside the folder, I have one file contain of information that I will use to mapping.
This is the folder looks like:

```
Folder1: 12345ABCD
Folder2: 67890EFGH
Folder3: 112233AAB
```

Inside of each folder has a file, like this:

```
Folder1: ID.txt : contain of string 123 456
Folder2: ID.txt : contain of string 789 111
Folder3: ID.txt : contain of string 222 333
```

Instead of those 3 file, I have another files inside those folder to process.

I have a variable $ID_PC contain of string, I want to match `$ID_PC` with those folder. For the example, my `$ID_PC = "789"`, It means, match to `Folder2`, so I will read all the files in the `Folder2` to do next process.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem? I am newbie with PowerShell. Thank you.

```
‘$ID_PC = “789”’
‘$Path_Folder = “./Folder/“‘
‘$Get_ID = Get-Content -Path “$Path_Folder/*.txt” |      Where-Object -Contain $ID_PC’
```

Comment: You're description is a bit confusing - please post the actual code you're currently trying to use (even if it doesn't work)

Comment: I updated it, but I do not how to write the code to check which folder that match with $ID_PC.

Comment: Actually, I want to decide, which folder should I choose, consider with $ID_PC by matching with ID.txt file. ID.txt contain of string, thats why I need to get the content of ID.txt as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO the naming Folder1..3 is completely irrelevant.

Assuming a tree like this

```
PS A:\> tree /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 5566-7788
A:.
└───Test
    ├───112233AAB
    │       ID.txt                  contains string 123 456
    │
    ├───12345ABCD
    │       ID.txt                  contains string 789 111
    │
    └───67890EFGH
            ID.txt                  contains string 222 333
```

This command:

```
Get-ChildItem A:\Test\*\ID.txt | Select-String -Pattern '789'
```

yields:

```
Test\12345ABCD\ID.txt:1:contains string 789 111
```

That matchinfo object could be evaluated further to extract just the folder name. I.e:

```
PS A:\> (Get-Item (Get-ChildItem A:\Test\*\ID.txt | Select-String -Pattern '789').Path).Directory.FullName
A:\Test\12345ABCD
```

Comment: Wow, That's what I need. Thank you @LotPings